# Django ImproperlyConfigured at

Tags: python, django

Estoy empezando a usar multitenant pero no he podido avanzar porque me sale este error:

[image: Error]

Yo no he cambiado nada en las URLs, les comparto mi distribución de archivos:

[image: Dist]

El archivo principal urls.py del proyecto (pruebatenant) es:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # solo en servidor de desarrollo

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),

    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page':'login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^cambiar-pass/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name':'cambiar-pass.html', 'post_change_redirect':'login'}, name='cambiar_pass'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='publico/index.html'), name='home'),

    url(r'^publico/', include('publico.urls')),
    url(r'^personas/', include('personas.urls')),

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

El urls.py de personas es:
    `from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('personas.views.persona',
    url(r'^nueva_persona$', 'nueva_persona', name="nueva_persona"),
)
```

y el urls.py de publico es:
    `from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('publico.views.principal',
    url(r'^inicio$', 'inicio', name="inicio"),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('publico.views.empresas',
    url(r'^nueva_empresa$', 'nueva_empresa', name="nueva_empresa"),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diana, el problema no es tus URLs, el problema está en tu `settings.py`, si estás usando el [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/) framework (como se muestra en el error de la imagen), tienes que definir el [`SITE_ID`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-SITE_ID) en tu configuración:

```
# settings.py
...
SITE_ID = 1
...
```

Esto debería bastar para que funcione tu aplicación. Si tu intención no es usarlo, asegúrate de removerlo o comentarlo en tu `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
# settings.py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'django.contrib.sites'
    ...
)
...
```